# com.ontbee.legacyforks.cn.pedant.SweetAlert. SweetAlertDialog: Unknown animation name: Rotate3dAnimation error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I want to show a Sweet Alert Dialog thanks to the API com.ontbee.legacyforks.cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog , which is censed to avoid the exception "Unknown animation name: util.cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation error:util.cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation" to be thrown (cf. https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog/issues/162's answers).

However, the above exception actually is thrown, the full exception is:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.androidframework, PID: 30700
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: util.cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation
>   error:util.cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation
>           at com.ontbee.legacyforks.cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.createAnimationFromXml(OptAnimationLoader.java:77)
>           at com.ontbee.legacyforks.cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.createAnimationFromXml(OptAnimationLoader.java:64)
>           at com.ontbee.legacyforks.cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.createAnimationFromXml(OptAnimationLoader.java:41)
>           at com.ontbee.legacyforks.cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.loadAnimation(OptAnimationLoader.java:22)
>           at com.ontbee.legacyforks.cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog.(SweetAlertDialog.java:81)
>           at fragments.posts.FragmentPosts.onCreateView(FragmentPosts.java:74)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

## What I have done

1. In the App Level Gradle, I added: `implementation 'com.github.thomper:sweet-alert-dialog:1.4.0'`
2. In the Project Level Gradle, I added:

   allprojects {
       repositories {
           ...
           maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
       }
3. In my fragment or something like that, I added:

`import com.ontbee.legacyforks.cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog;`

```
  SweetAlertDialog pDialog2 = new SweetAlertDialog(that, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE);
                        pDialog2.setTitleText(getResources().getString(R.string.error_occured));
                        pDialog2.setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.unkown_error));
                        pDialog2.show();
```

## Expected behavior

With com.ontbee.legacyforks.cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog ,  normally this exception should not be thrown. The original API was from cn.pendant repo (which leads to this exception).

The expected behavior is: the dialog is shown without exception.

Comment: any solution you got? I faced this when applied the minifying and resources shrinking

Comment: I will take a look at my sources to tell you I did or not have a solution :) this evening, tomorrow or this week. OK? :)